# Express Gateway: Not getting response body

Tags: express-gateway

I am not being able to get the response body that I need to store in the logs along with the request body. The only time I'm able to get the response body is when the request fails.

I've followed the blog post that solved my issue on getting the request body while using body-parser plugin - https://www.express-gateway.io/exploit-request-stream/.

```
const { PassThrough } = require("stream");
const jsonParser = require("express").json();
const urlEncodedParser = require("express").urlencoded({ extended: true });

module.exports = {
  name: 'body-parser',
  policy: actionParams => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
      req.egContext.requestStream = new PassThrough()
      req.pipe(req.egContext.requestStream)

      return jsonParser(req, res, () => urlEncodedParser(req, res, next))
      }
    }
};
```

When the request does work:

```
{ res: { statusCode: 400 },
  req:
   { body: { a: 'b' },
     headers:
      { ... } },
  responseTime: 310 }
```

When it does not work:

```
{ res: { body: 'Bad gateway.', statusCode: 502 },
req:
{ body: { a: 'b' },
headers:
{ ... } },
responseTime: 1019 }
```

Answer (score 1):

this code alone is not enough to get the response body. This will simply hook in the request body processing and make it available to EG in a parsed way. In case you want to hook in the response too, you will need to write an hook in the response object, once it's done.

You can find an example code [here](https://github.com/ExpressGateway/express-gateway/pull/864/files#diff-18a24ed329ffcb6d9f54de59f74a814fR9)

I hope that helps!

V.